# Passing variables to email template not working

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, emails

I am building a Craft plugin which sends emails to users of a subscribed list. I'm trying to get Craft to send the email with a Twig template and pass in variables to that template.

So far I've been able to get the Twig template working properly, except I'm having issues displaying the variables `heading` and `content` in my template. They are returned as plain text.

Here's my code for sending the email.

```php
$mailer = Craft::$app->mailer;
$mailer->htmlLayout = false;
$mailer->textLayout = false;
$mailer->setViewPath('@templates');

$mailer
   ->compose('emails/default.twig', [
      'heading' => $list->subject,
      'content' => "Something new has been posted on the Harvest Youth blog. <a href='{$entry->url}'>{$entry->title}</a>",
   ])
   ->setTo($subscriber->title)
   ->setSubject($list->subject)
   ->send();
```

Here's how I'm trying to use the variables in my Twig template.

```
<div style="margin: 4px;">
   <h1 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 30px;">{{ heading }}</h1>
   {{ content }}
</div>
```

And here's how the email template is returned.

[image]

I'd appreciate any help as I'm new to Craft plugins and I'm not fantastic with Twig either.

Comment: Have a look here - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35037/3630